# Accessing device in my subnet with a fixed IP

Tags: networking, routing, ubuntu-14.04, camera, arp

I've just purchased a cheap surveillance camera for my apartment. However, while the subnet in my apartment is 10.0.0.0/24, the camera comes with a fixed IP of 192.168.1.10. You can change the IP, but you have to connect to it first.

I can see in Wireshark the unanswered arp requests of the camera to 192.168.1.1. So I decided to 2 arp entries in my computer to bind for 192.168.1.1 (direct it to my routers MAC), and to 192.168.1.10 (direct it to the camera's mac).

I set those entries to be "published", I thought it means my computer will answer for an arp requests of the camera, and the router.

When adding the router as a published entry, with this command line:

```
sudo arp -s -i wlan0 192.168.1.1 e8:fc:af:89:c6:e0 pub
```

I get this entry -

```
192.168.1.1 * "from_interface" MP wlan0
```

Unfortunately, my computer doesn't respond to any of the camera's arp requests.

Am I taking the wrong approach here? What can I do otherwise to access the camera? And why wouldn't my computer answer to the camera's arp requests?

Answer (score 0):

Manually give your computer a 192.168.1.x/24 IP address. That's all you have to do.

You shouldn't have to hand-create ARP mappings or routes or worry about router addresses or what other subnets other devices on your LAN happen to be using. In fact you should delete the bogus ARP mapping you created on your computer that pointed 192.168.1.1 to your router. If your router doesn't know it's supposed to be 192.168.1.1, trying to send it frames for 192.168.1.1 won't do any good.

If you do end up having to manually create a static ARP mapping to map the camera's IP address to the camera's MAC address, then it's a sign that something's broken in your network. It's a sign that multicast/broadcast packets aren't getting delivered everywhere they need to be.

Comment: The device wouldn't be able to reply that way, since its trying to address its replies to 192.168.1.1, which do not exist in my network.

Comment: @Satya When replying to addresses on its own subnet, it should ARP for, and then reply directly to, other devices on that subnet. I would be surprised if that device wasn't using a /24 subnet mask. But if what you say is true, and for some reason it only wants to talk to 192.168.1.1, then just give your computer the 192.168.1.1 address.